# Водяной знак на изображении средствами PHP

Tags: php

Добрый день! Есть такой механизм, человек добавляет товар, выбирает фотки и фотки загружаются на сервер, имена фоток записываются в БД. После этого я делаю что бы на фотку накладывался водяной знак. На Php.net Нашел официальную функцию для работы с ними.

```
// Загрузка штампа и фото, для которого применяется водяной знак (называется штамп или печать)
$stamp = imagecreatefrompng('images/stamp.png');
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadfile);

// Установка полей для штампа и получение высоты/ширины штампа
$marge_right = 10;
$marge_bottom = 10;
$sx = imagesx($stamp);
$sy = imagesy($stamp);
// Копирование изображения штампа на фотографию с помощью смещения края
// и ширины фотографии для расчета позиционирования штампа. 
imagecopy($im, $stamp, imagesx($im) - $sx - $marge_right, 
imagesy($im) - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), 
imagesy($stamp));

// Вывод и освобождение памяти
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Но вот вопрос, фото то я уже загрузил, а как мне загрузить фото уже с водяным знаком?

Comment: "уже с водяным знаком" в смысле это какая-то админиская функция? пользователи ведь не могут добавлять изображения уже с водяным знаком?

Comment: Есть объективные причины чтобы не добавлять водяной знак когда пользователь загружает изображение? Зачем это делать потом? Или я что-то не так понял?